# Signing product flavors with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle, code-signing

I am tyring to migrate my projects to gradle. One of my projects has multiple product flavors and each one of them has to be signed with a different `signingConfig` in its release version. So this is what I tried so far:

```
buildscript {
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '17'

    signingConfigs {
        flavor1 {
            storeFile file("keystore")
            storePassword "secret"
            keyAlias "aliasForFlavor1"
            keyPassword "secretFlavor1"
        }

        flavor2 {
            storeFile file("keystore")
            storePassword "secret"
            keyAlias "aliasForFlavor2"
            keyPassword "secretFlavor2"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor1
        }

        flavor1 {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor2
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

When I run `gradle build` I get a `groovy.lang.MissingFieldException` and the following error message:

```
No such field: signingConfigs for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.GroupableProductFlavorFactory
```

So I assume the `productFlavors`.* part of the Gradle script is not the right place to put code signing configurations.

Comment: The solution works well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40124853/3256989

Comment: Here's a related question for those asking about why the `debug` builds are not picking up the flavor config.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618363/override-debug-build-type-signing-config-with-flavor-signing-config

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Per the [user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), signingConfigs for flavors are supported.

The problem here has to do with the scope of the signingConfigs object.  I just assigned it to a variable inside the `productFlavors` block, but outside the `flavor1` flavor block to fix the issue:

```
productFlavors {
    def flavor1SigningVariable = signingConfigs.flavor1

    flavor1 {
        ...
        signingConfig flavor1SigningVariable
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This really shouldn't be required. I filed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64701 to track this.

Comment: The solution seems broken in Gradle v2.4

Comment: In my case it worked after adding android.buildTypes.debug.signingConfig = null; and android.buildTypes.relese.signingConfig = null; to clear base signing. It means signingConfig in buildTypes overrides signingConfig in  a flavor. Even default one which Android create automatically. You can check it with printing android.buildTypes.debug.signingConfig for example

Comment: What if you want to have this flavor with two different signing configs? release/debug? I think that this way is more elegant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35057525/2557258

Comment: Thank you for `android.buildTypes.debug.signingConfig = null;`, I wasted an entire afternoon until I saw that small comment. Might be worth adding that to the main response.

Comment: @Alexey your comment saved my life. Using Gradle KTS flavor signing was ignored all the time. Had same configuration using plane Gradle, no issues. With Gradle KTS it's required to reset the signing config of your build types `android.buildTypes.relese.signingConfig=null` first. Guess that's a bug.

Comment: If you are struggling to get this to work - try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618363/override-debug-build-type-signing-config-with-flavor-signing-config/29618981

The linked approach has worked for me for years.

Answer (score 115):

You can declare `signing config` for each `flavor` in `buildType`. Here is my gradle file for release signing flavors with different keystores.

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    configFirst {
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword 'password'
        storeFile file('first.keystore')
        storePassword 'password'
    }

    configSecond {
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword 'password'
        storeFile file('second.keystore')
        storePassword 'password'
    }
  }

  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
  defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
  }

  productFlavors{
    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.test.firstapp"
    }

    flavor2 {
        applicationId "com.test.secondapp"
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        productFlavors.flavor1.signingConfig signingConfigs.configFirst
        productFlavors.flavor2.signingConfig signingConfigs.configSecond           

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
  }
}
```

`buildTypes` block should be placed after `productFlavors` block, I mean order is important.

Comment: It work very well. I checked it with signingReport task and all build types/flavors signed with necessary key. Should be marked as right answer.

Comment: Good solution, but for me works only with release build type. My debug build type, with the exact same signingConfigs declarations, gets signed with ~/.android/debug.keystore key. For the particular project I am working on I need to properly sign my debug builds.

Comment: @mtsahakis just create `debug {...}` block in `buildTypes ` and declare there signing configs for debug builds.

Comment: @almaz_from_kazan I did that initially, had a `debug {productFlavors.flavor1.signingConfig signingConfigs.configFirst}` but it was not picking up the signingConfigs, so I switched to `debug.initWith(buildTypes.release)
debug {}` without `productFlavors.flavor1.signingConfig signingConfigs.configFirst` and signing is now as working as intended for debug builds. Thanks!

Comment: Android adds a default `signingConfig` for debug builds. Remove it by passing `null`, like this: `buildTypes { debug { signingConfig null } }`. By doing this, you delegate the `signingConfig` to the product flavors.

Comment: Good answer, it is worth noting that `buildTypes` **must be after** `productFlavors`.

Comment: Worked well...be sure to remove "signingConfig signingConfigs.release" from your release config or the other ones won't override it...I thought they would override this and I could use it as a default.

Comment: Does this even work? If I iterate `applicationVariants` afterwards, all build types have the same signing configurations that were specified in the last build type.

Comment: @AllanHasegawa thank you so much... this answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426636/android-flavors-signing-not-working-as-expected . I had this impression that Android was doing something by default. After so many days you finally solved for me. Thanks again.

Comment: If you guys are struggling to get this to work, you can also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618363/override-debug-build-type-signing-config-with-flavor-signing-config/29618981

Comment: I disagree with @EpicPandaForce; the order of `buildTypes` after `productFlavors` is not mandatory but should be for better readability.

Answer (score 9):

The gradle plugin for android only supports signing per build type, not per flavor. The reason for this is that any given *variant* (build type + flavors) can only be signed by one key, but can be a combination of several flavor groups. For example your flavor groups could be cpu (x86/arm) and version (free/paid), that's four different variants right there.

The solution you're looking for is to create separate build types for your different release versions. For example, your build types might be `debug`, `release`, `release-beta`, like this:

```
...

android {

    ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        release-beta {
            initWith release
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release-beta
        }
    }
}
```

The `initWith` above just tells gradle that `release-beta` should be a copy of the `release` build type, only signed with a different key.

Comment: You can actually put `buildTypes` in the `productFlavors` (I'm not sure if that's a new thing though)

Comment: @pjco putting `buildTypes` inside `productFlavors` sounds like a helpful solution to this question of mine - http://stackoverflow.com/q/30898611/383414 - if you have the time to have a look

Comment: @pjco yeah, i did `builtTypes{ release {productFlavors.pro.versionCode 1} }`

Answer (score 7):

### Maybe another interesting solution with dynamic flavor signing configs and other advantages

- Im fine with defining app id and app name of flavors in gradle (it is clear and just 2 lines for each flavor) but I do not want to define separate signing configs (gradle file would be too long when adding flavors)
- I also do not want to have sensitive signing information placed in gradle because of commiting it
- Bonus advantage is that debug build has another app id and app name.

**.gitignore**

```
...
/keystore.properties
```

**.keystore.properties**

```
storeFile=../mystore.jks
storePassword=...

keyAliasFlavor1=...
keyPasswordFlavor1=...

keyAliasFlavor2=...
keyPasswordFlavor2=...
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file('keystore.properties')))

android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
            manifestPlaceholders = [appNameSuffix: " Dev"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        release {
            ...
            manifestPlaceholders = [appNameSuffix: ""]
            productFlavors.all { flavor ->
                flavor.signingConfig = android.signingConfigs.create("${flavor.name}")
                flavor.signingConfig.storeFile = rootProject.file(keystoreProperties["storeFile"])
                flavor.signingConfig.storePassword = keystoreProperties["storePassword"]
                flavor.signingConfig.keyAlias = keystoreProperties["keyAlias${flavor.name}"]
                flavor.signingConfig.keyPassword = keystoreProperties["keyPassword${flavor.name}"]
            }
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        Flavor1 {
            applicationId "..."
            manifestPlaceholders = [appNameBase: "MyApp 1"]
        }
        Flavor2 {
            applicationId "..."
            manifestPlaceholders = [appNameBase: "MyApp 2"]
        }
        // ... and many other flavors without taking care about signing configs
        // (just add two lines into keystore.properties for each new flavor)
    }
}
```

app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <application android:label="${appNameBase}${appNameSuffix}" ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The bit around dynamically creating the signingConfig was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: Exactly what I needed. We use this to split our signing configs between GMS and HMS
--->
productFlavors.all { flavor ->
                if (flavour.name.toLowerCase() == "gms") {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                }
                if (flavour.name.toLowerCase() == "hms") {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseHms
                }
            }

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) equivalent of [*ashakirov*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35057525/8583692):

```kotlin
// See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60474010
fun getLocalProperty(key: String) = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty(key)
fun String?.toFile() = file(this!!)
// Could also use System.getenv("VARIABLE_NAME") to get each variable individually
val environment: Map<String, String> = System.getenv()

android {
    signingConfigs {
        create("MyFirstConfig") {
            keyAlias = getLocalProperty("signing.keyAlias") ?: environment["SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS"]
            storeFile = (getLocalProperty("signing.storeFile") ?: environment["SIGNING_STORE_FILE"]).toFile()
            keyPassword = getLocalProperty("signing.keyPassword") ?: environment["SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD"]
            storePassword = getLocalProperty("signing.storePassword") ?: environment["SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD"]
            enableV1Signing = true
            enableV2Signing = true
        }
        create("MySecondConfig") {
            keyAlias = getLocalProperty("signing.keyAlias2") ?: environment["SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS2"]
            storeFile = (getLocalProperty("signing.storeFile2") ?: environment["SIGNING_STORE_FILE2"]).toFile()
            keyPassword = getLocalProperty("signing.keyPassword2") ?: environment["SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD2"]
            storePassword = getLocalProperty("signing.storePassword2") ?: environment["SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD2"]
            enableV1Signing = true
            enableV2Signing = true
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        create("flavor1") {
            // ...
        }
        create("flavor2") {
            // ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") { // OR simply  release {  in newer versions of Android Gradle Plugin (AGP)
            productFlavors["flavor1"].signingConfig = signingConfigs["MyFirstConfig"]
            productFlavors["flavor2"].signingConfig = signingConfigs["MySecondConfig"]
            // OR alternative notation
            // productFlavors {
            //     getByName("flavor1") {
            //         signingConfig = signingConfigs["MyFirstConfig"]
            //     }
            //     getByName("flavor2") {
            //         signingConfig = signingConfigs["MySecondConfig"]
            //     }
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Split signing configs between `Gms` and `Hms` builds

Just for future ref if anyone has to split their signing configs between `Gms` and `Hms` builds.

This adds on the the answer listed here:
**Maybe another interesting solution with dynamic flavor signing configs and other advantages**

---

build.gradle

##### Option 1

`gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames().each()`

```
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

   signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties["RELEASE_STORE_FILE"])
            storePassword keystoreProperties["RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD"]
            keyAlias keystoreProperties["RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS"]
            keyPassword keystoreProperties["RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD"]
        }
        releaseHms {
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties["RELEASE_HMS_STORE_FILE"])
            storePassword keystoreProperties["RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD"]
            keyAlias keystoreProperties["RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS"]
            keyPassword keystoreProperties["RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD"]
        }
        debug {
            // use default debug key to sign
        }
    }
    
   buildTypes {
        release {
            ...

            gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames().each { task ->
                if (task.toLowerCase().contains("gms")) {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                }
                if (task.toLowerCase().contains("hms") {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseHms
                }
            }
        }

        debug {
            ...

            gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames().each { task ->
                if (task.toLowerCase().contains("gms")) {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                }
                if (task.toLowerCase().contains("hms") {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseHms
                }
            }

        flavorDimensions "serviceplatform"
        productFlavors {
        hms {
            dimension "serviceplatform"
            applicationIdSuffix ".huawei"
            versionNameSuffix "-huawei"
        }
        gms {
            dimension "serviceplatform"
            applicationIdSuffix ".android"
        }
     }

   sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = [
                    "src/main/res",
                    "src/main/res/layout/toolbar",
                    "src/main/res/layout/fragment",
                    "src/main/res/layout/activity"
            ]
        }

        gms {
            java.srcDir("src/gms/java")
        }
        hms {
            java.srcDir("src/hms/java")
        }
    }
```

##### Option 2

`productFlavors.gms.signingConfig`

Ensure your `flavorDimensions` is before `buildTypes`

```
flavorDimensions "serviceplatform"
     productFlavors {
        hms {
            ...
        }
        gms {
            ...
        }
    }

buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            productFlavors.gms.signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            productFlavors.hms.signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseHms
        }

        debug {
            ...
            productFlavors.gms.signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            productFlavors.hms.signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseHms
        }
    }
```