# Override debug build type signing config with flavor signing config

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've got an Android app that has 2 flavors: `internal` and `production`, and there are 2 build types as well: `debug` and `release`.

I'm trying to assign signing configs based on the flavor, which according to the documentation is doable. I've looked and found other answers to this, but none of them seem to work. Everything compiles, but the app is being signed with the debug keystore local to my machine.

Here is my gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        internal {
            storeFile file("../internal.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "user"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
        production {
            storeFile file("../production.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "user"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        internal {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.internal
            applicationId 'com.test.test.internal'
        }
        production {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.production
            applicationId 'com.test.test'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".d"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals('debug')
                && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('production')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I'm also compiling with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'`

Comment: Here is the best way how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35057525/2557258

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It seems that by default, Android has a `signingConfig` set on the debug build type (the android debug keystore), and when the `signingConfig` is set for the build type, the `signingConfig` is ignored for the flavor.

The solution is to set the `signingConfig` to `null` on the debug build type. Then the `signingConfig` given for the flavor will be used instead:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            // Set to null to override default debug keystore and defer to the product flavor.
            signingConfig null
            applicationIdSuffix ".d"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, why the `.d` on `applicationIdSuffix`? Is that necessary?

Comment: No, it's not. I give my debug builds a separate package than my release builds, so they can be installed on the same device without interfering with one another. I'd highly recommend it though :-)

Comment: It might be a little more descriptive to others if ".d" would be ".debug", but both work of course ;-)

Comment: It is not necessary to set debug key to null. We can set unique key for each type and flavor: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35057525/2557258

Comment: Hats off for your answer. Saving my flavor concept project.. Working for me

Comment: Wow, this isn't very intuitive. Thanks for this answer! Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: I don't think it's documented anywhere. I found it just by fiddling around.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thanks for updating your question with the answer.

Comment: You're my hero!

Comment: @Yazon2006 I tried that. It doesn't work. The accepted answer does the trick for me.

Comment: Has anyone found this documented anywhere?

Comment: @AbhishekJain It will not work in case if you defined signinConfig only for one of flavors. So you must apply signinConfig for each flavor combination OR define fallback "null" value.