# why run the app directly in Android Studio，the result apk is unsigned

Tags: android, android-studio

I have configured the signature in the buildType code block, but when I run the app directly in Android Studio, the obtained apk is still unsigned, and I cannot get the signature information in the apk.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU374.png)
My build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('G:\\source\\AndroidSamples\\DiyView\\hwj.jks')
        storePassword '123456'
        keyAlias 'key0'
        keyPassword '123456'
    }
    release {
        storeFile file('G:\\source\\AndroidSamples\\DiyView\\hwj.jks')
        storePassword '123456'
        keyAlias 'key0'
        keyPassword '123456'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

apksigner verify -v .\app-debug.apk
DOES NOT VERIFY
ERROR: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 0):

Change the build variant to release.

Simplest way is:

- double tap left shift key.
- Write variants.
- Click on build variants
- Select release from the dropdown.

At this point, click on Play button again.

Android Studio will install a signed apk.

Comment: As far as Ive read "by default, Android has a signingConfig set on the debug build type (the android debug keystore), and when the signingConfig is set for the build type, the signingConfig is ignored for the flavor."
Check this answer to read more about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618363/override-debug-build-type-signing-config-with-flavor-signing-config
It should work for a release apk, considering that.

Comment: Where have you read that it´s impossible to do it? Kindly post your own question on your own thread and I´ll gladly help you out too. Do you have a similar problem? Have you tried the provided answer?

Comment: Kindly read the answer provided in the link above - I´m sure it will help you out. Fidlle with it a bit and you´ll get it.