# apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the Project Structure dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have looked at two SO threads for this and none have a selected Answer for this error message because no Answer candidate exactly addresses it.

```
   apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected 
   flavor using the Project Structure dialog
```

I've successfully uploaded both `debug` `apk`s to Google Play Store for beta testing and had no problems.

My only question for now is: I have `debug` versions of the two build variants. **Do I need to have `release` versions for ANY reason?**

**If not, fine. Case closed.**

If I DO NEED RELEASE VERSIONS, though, I need help.

*** EDIT ***

OK. I need release version. The link in the first answer below says:

`(1) Create a keystore. A keystore is a binary file that contains a set of private keys. You must keep your keystore in a safe and secure place.`

I've read that the first time I compiled my app I created a keystore. So on to:

`(2) Create a private key. A private key represents the entity to be identified with the app, such as a person or a company.`

How do I do THIS?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had long ago successfully used build variants to upload to Google Play Store (GPS) 'debug' apks for both free and full version of app for beta testing.

That wasn't the question. The question was whether I need to knock myself out to **produce 'release' apks** (how to do so is not clear) and upload them.

The answer is **NO**. App is for sale as we speak at GPS in form of 'debug' apk for each version. All it took was "promoting" the beta versions by moving them to production.

*** EDIT ***

I am able to upload `release` versions of the two `apk`s to GPS without being able to compile them in AS 1.2.1 (because of the error in the title of this post).

This was an accident. Seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
To have two different APKs in the Play Store, you would need a different package name for each flavor (look at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename to learn how to achieve this). Each APK should have to be signed separately. There is a good explanation on how to create signing keys in http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio. After you have two keys you can define them as explained in [stackoverflow.com/questions/17040494/signing-product-flavors-with-gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040494/signing-product-flavors-with-gradle).

Comment: Please see edited question. Note that I have used build variants so that one project creates two apks-- one for free, one for full version.

Comment: I have two different package names and just uploaded latest versions successfully.

Comment: Glad to hear I was able to help you.