# Not able to signed the apk based on buildtypes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

our Application support different product flavour with different client so we have different keystore file. we need to signed the build based on buildtypes like. "Debug","release","production".

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig null
        }
        release {
            signingConfig null
        }
        production {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
            android.txt'), 'proguard-production.pro'
            applicationIdSuffix ".production"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        A {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('xxxx')
            storePassword 'xxxx'
        }

        B {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('xxxx')
            storePassword 'xxxx'
        }

        C {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('xxxx')
            storePassword 'xxxx'
        }

        D {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('xxxx')
            storePassword 'xxxx'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        X {
            if (buildTypes == "production") {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.A
            }
        }
        Y {
            if (buildTypes == "production") {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.B
            }

        }
        Z {

            if (buildTypes == "production") {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.C
            }

        }

    }
}
```

we need the solution like whatever i mentioned in code section area.
please help me to solve this problem statement.

```
thank you in advance
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signing product flavors with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040494/signing-product-flavors-with-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it may help you**

```
signingConfigs {

        Alias1Config {
            keyAlias 'keyAlis1'
            keyPassword '123456789'
            storeFile file('D:/ABS/XYZ/keyAlis1.jks')
            storePassword '1234567989'
        }

        Alias2Config {
            keyAlias 'keyAlis2'
            keyPassword '123456789'
            storeFile file('D:/ABS/XYZ/keyAlis1.jks')
            storePassword '1234567989'
        }

    }

productFlavors {
        aliasV1 {
            applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Alias1Config
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", "ABC_APP_$versionName.$versionCode")
        }
        aliasV2 {
            applicationId "com.abc.xyz.pqr"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Alias2Config
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", "PQR_APP_$versionName.$versionCode")
        }

    }
```

Comment: hi vishrut,

thank for answer but it will signed the apk for all buildtypes i.e debug,release,production but i want to signed only production apk . please suggest me