# Generate multiple apk with multiple keystore files

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using the [following instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits) in Android Studio for generating multiple APKs:

```
android {
  ...
  splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {

      // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
      enable true

      // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
      // want APKs for x86 and x86_64.

      // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
      reset()

      // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
      include "x86", "x86_64"

      // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
      universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```

The question is: how can I assign a different *keystore* for every different APK? I've found no instructions on the official guide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Lore you can not create or define different keystores or keystores' details for expansion, because this is just expansion of the same *APK*, for expansion you can follow below document:
[Configure build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

You can define keystore data and create *apk* for different flavors: 
[Link for define keystore data in product flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35057525/3894930)