# Read value from local.properties via Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to retreive key from `local.properties` file that looks like :

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\i30mb1\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
key="xxx"
```

and save this value in my `BuildConfig.java` via gradle Kotlin DSL. And later get access to this field from my project.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Okay. I found solutions.

**For Android Projects :**

1. In my build.gradle.kts I create a value that retrieves my key:

```kotlin
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties

val key: String = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("key")
```

2. And in the block `buildTypes` I write it:

```kotlin
buildTypes {
 getByName("debug") {
    buildConfigField("String", "key", key)
   }
}
```

3. And in my Activity now I can retrieve this value:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    val key = BuildConfig.key
}
```

**For Kotlin Projects:**

1. We can create an extension that help us to retrieve desired key:

```
fun Project.getLocalProperty(key: String, file: String = "local.properties"): Any {
    val properties = java.util.Properties()
    val localProperties = File(file)
    if (localProperties.isFile) {
        java.io.InputStreamReader(java.io.FileInputStream(localProperties), Charsets.UTF_8).use { reader ->
            properties.load(reader)
        }
    } else error("File from not found")

    return properties.getProperty(key)
}
```

2. And use this extension when we would like

```
task("printKey") {
   doLast {
       val key = getLocalProperty("key")
       println(key)
   }
}
```

Comment: What's `gradleLocalProperties`?

Comment: Is there a similar function for plain kotlin projects?

Comment: **Unresolved reference: gradleLocalProperties**

Comment: For plain kotlin projects you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69268957/1118475

Comment: that 'gradleLocalProperties' requires a provider parameter. as im using that line of code in recente builds i found that >  ` gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).apply {`                                     ^ No value passed for parameter 'providers'.

Answer (score 41):

If you don't have access to `gradleLocalProperties` (it's only accessible for android projects):

```
val prop = Properties().apply {
    load(FileInputStream(File(rootProject.rootDir, "local.properties")))
}
println("Property:" + prop.getProperty("propertyName"))
```

Don't forget imports:

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.*
```

Comment: This is a much better solution, thanks. Not only is the accepted answer specific to Android projects, it uses an API from an internal package which is probably not officially supported.

Comment: rootProject undefined. How do you retrieve rootDir ?

Comment: you can call rootProject.projectdir

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

put your property in
local.properties

and in build.gradle(app).kts file reference it as such:
gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("YOUR_PROP_NAME")

Answer (score 3):

I might be late here to answer but out of the above answer one thing is missing is to set buildConfig value to true of buildFeature.

```
android{
    buildFeatures 
        buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

In my case what I followed is:

local.properties file

```
sdk.dir=/home/username/user/software/android-sdk
API_KEY=kE949ziieWGGyk8skRSk93gGd
```

Also,you need to read and define your build config field in app-level file

> build.gradle

```
android{
    buildTypes {
        release {
           val p = Properties()   
           p.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").reader())
           val yourKey: String = p.getProperty("API_KEY") 
           buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"$yourKey\"")
        }

        debug {
          val p = Properties()   
          p.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").reader())
          val yourKey: String = p.getProperty("API_KEY") 
          buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"$yourKey\"")
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example note that I have used two different keys for both release and debug build.

**Note Important:** After all these changes, sync your project, clean the build, re-build it, and then use the build config build like:

```
BuildConfig.API_KEY
```

Comment: unable to resolve class val

Answer (score 1):

for me the complete solution in android projects was :

1 - put your key in local properties.

2 - in build.gradle.kts => add 2 lines

```
val key: String = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("KEY") ?: ""
buildConfigField("String", "KEY", "\"$key\"")
```

### == now you can get your key in code like this:

```
val key = BuildConfig.KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

To read properties inside the gradle file it can be done with

```
import java.util.Properties

android {
    compileSdkVersion(Config.Android.compileSdkVersion)
    buildToolsVersion = Config.Android.buildToolsVersion
  
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(Config.Android.minSdkVersion)
        versionCode = Config.Libs.versionCode
        versionName = Config.Libs.versionName
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "${project.name}-${versionName}(${versionCode})")

        val projectProperties = readProperties(file("../project.properties"))

        buildConfigField("String", "STATIC_VECTOR", projectProperties["staticVector1"] as String)
    }
  
}

fun readProperties(propertiesFile: File) = Properties().apply {
    propertiesFile.inputStream().use { fis ->
        load(fis)
    }
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/gtomek/b56477df158eb49f1bb7eeda95b3e14d)